# Why `functools.cached_property` can work as a decorator without `__new__` or `__call__`?

Tags: python, open-source, python-decorators

In my undertstanding, decorator class should contain `__call__` or `__new__` method. But cached_property in [cpython repo](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/python/cpython/-/blob/Lib/functools.py?L981&subtree=true) doesn't follow the rules. Can anyone explain it for me?

```
class cached_property:
    def __init__(self, func):
        xxx

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        xxx
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        xxx

    __class_getitem__ = classmethod(GenericAlias)
```

Comment: I omit the function body in order to post successfully, please follow the cpython link to see full code.

Comment: Post an excerpt of the code instead of just a link.

Comment: decorators can be callables is general so functions, classes (will do init or new) or class instances (those need call) and should return a function/callable again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do all decorator classes need `__call__`?**

> decorator class should contain `__call__` or `__new__` method

Not all decorator classes need to implement `__call__`.
It's only required when we want to call the decorated object with `()`.

- A decorator class that takes a callable to produce a callable has to implement `__call__`.
  In this example, `__call__` is implemented *because we want to do `data.calculate()`*.

  ```py
  # Decorator to call and cache the function immediately
  class PreCompute:
      def __init__(self, func):
          self.value = func()

      def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
          return self.value

  class Data:
      @PreCompute
      def calculate():
          print("Data.calculate called")
          return 42

  data = Data()
  # This actually calls PreCompute's __call__
  print(data.calculate())
  ```

  The definition of `class Data` here is roughly desugared to something like this,
  so when calling `data.calculate()` we're actually calling the `__call__` function from `class PreCompute`.

  ```py
  class Data:
      def calculate():
          print("Data.calculate called")
          return 42
      calculate = PreCompute(calculate)
  ```
- A decorator class that takes a callable but does not produce a callable does **not** have to implement `__call__`.
  For example, we can modify the `class Precompute` decorator to the following code, which allows us to access `data.calculate` as if it's an attribute.
  For more information about what `__get__` does, see [Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) from Python docs.

  ```py
  class PreCompute:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.value = func()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

  class Data:
      @PreCompute
      def calculate():
          print("Data.calculate called")
          return 42

  data = Data()
  # Access .calculate like an attribute
  print(data.calculate)
  ```

**What about `__new__`?**

I'm not sure how OP got the impression that decorator classes must define either `__call__` or `__new__`. I've seen `__new__` being defined for use cases like [`@singleton` decorator for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760685/12122460), but as discussed in the previous section about `__call__`, this is also not strictly required. The only function we must define is an `__init__` that receives the object to be decorated.

**How does `@functools.cached_property` work, then?**

Now going back to the question, notice from [the documentation of `@functools.cached_property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property) that
it "transform a method of a class into a property", which is to be accessed without the parentheses `()`.
Therefore, [`class cached_property` implements `__get__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2e279e85fece187b6058718ac7e82d1692461e26/Lib/functools.py#L981) but not `__call__`, which is similar to the second example above.